# RegEx array / list / collection of all matches in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to **use RegEx** to get all instances of varying strings that exist in between a particular pair set of strings. E.g. in the following string:

`"The Start. Hello. Jamie. Bye. The Middle. Hello. Sarah. Bye. The End"`

I want to get a collection / array consisting of `"Jamie"` and `"Sarah"` by checking in between `"Hello. "` and `". Bye. "`

My RegEx object is working fine and I feel I'm nearly successful:

```
Sub Reggie()
Dim x As String: x = "The Start. Hello. Jamie. Bye. The Middle. Hello. Sarah. Bye. The End"
Dim regEx As RegExp
Set regEx = New RegExp
Dim rPat1 As String: rPat1 = "Hello. "
Dim rPat2 As String: rPat2 = " Bye."
Dim rPat3 As String: rPat3 = ".*"
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "(^.*" & rPat1 & ")(" & rPat3 & ")(" & rPat2 & ".*)"
    .MultiLine = True
    ' COMMAND HERE
End With
End Sub
```

But the last bit `COMMAND HERE` I'm trying `.replace(x, "$2")` which gives me a string of the last instance of a match i.e. `Sarah`

I've tried `.Execute(x)` which gives me a `MatchCollection` object and when browsing the immediate window I see that object only has the last instance of a match.

Is what I'm requiring possible and how?

Comment: That is because `.*` matches as many any chars as possible. You need `rPat1 = "Hello\. "`, 
 `rPat2 = " Bye\."`, `rPat3 = ".*?"` and `.Pattern = rPat1 & "(" & rPat3 & ")" & rPat2`. Note that you need to escape special chars in regex patterns (here, `.` is special).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I am very inexperienced with RegEx, I was trying a few different combos with no success. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `.*` matches as many any chars as possible and you should not match the whole string by adding `.*` on both ends of your regular expression.

Besides, you need to escape special chars in the regex pattern, here, `.` is special as it matches any char other than a line break char.

You need to fix your regex declaration like

```
rPat1 = "Hello\. "
rPat2 = " Bye\."
rPat3 = ".*?"`
.Pattern = rPat1 & "(" & rPat3 & ")" & rPat2
```

Or, to further enhance the regex, you may

- Replace literal spaces with `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) or `\s+` (one or more whitespaces) to support any whitespace
- Match any non-word chars after the captures string with `\W+` or `\W*`.

```vb
rPat1 = "Hello\.\s*"
rPat2 = "\W+Bye\."
rPat3 = ".*?"`
.Pattern = rPat1 & "(" & rPat3 & ")" & rPat2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E3Mzm1/1/). *Details*:

- `Hello\.` - `Hello.` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\W+` - one or more chars other than ASCII letters/digits/`_`
- `Bye\.` - `Bye.` string.

Comment: OP says they want `Jamie` not `Jamie.` so would have suggested `.Pattern = "Hello\.\s*(.*?)\.\s*Bye\."` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I think any non-word chars can be matched then, `Hello\.\s*(.*?)\W+Bye\.` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/E3Mzm1/1/)).

Comment: Thanks, accepted, works perfectly and thanks for the link to regex101 - great for experimenting and testing